# "Must be connected to a terminal error" with screen -x command on a Linux Container

Tags: linux, containers, gnu-screen, proxmox

I am using Linux containers with Proxmox 4.
When I am connected on an Ubuntu 16.04 container with:

```
pct enter <id>
```

I run a script with screen and try to watch the process running with:

```
screen -x <processname>
```

I got the error:

> Must be connected to a terminal error

When I connect with:

```
ssh -t <user>@<container_ip>
```

It works, I can attach the display to the screen.

How can I use **screen -x** when I am connected with **pct enter** ?

Comment: Not clear what `-x` provides you. Did you try `screen -t -x ..` ? Good luck.

Comment: `screen -x` allow to display a background script launched with the screen command.
When I use the command `screen -t -x` I got the same error : _Must be connected to a terminal_.

Answer (score 17):

I found a solution that works for same case(https://www.svennd.be/screen-in-lxc-attach)

Execute this

> script /dev/null

Then you can run screen, et voila

Comment: That does not explain what the cause of the problem is, though; it merely bodges around it with a pseudoterminal.

Comment: What is does? I dont understand how it allows starting screen session?

Answer (score 6):

This is happening mostly because of the reason that you must have 
*switched user*
 to the current terminal user using the command `sudo su` or user changing command.
You will need to own the shell on which you are working.
You can do so by running this:
`script /dev/null`.

Alternatively,
You can restart the terminal session with the *user*(which was used when creating screen) and not coming to current user using 
*switch user commands*.

To know active screens :
`screen -list`

Comment: This explanation makes no sense at all.  `script` is not a command for owning a shell, and `sudo` is unrelated to a lack of a controlling terminal because it does not adjust the controlling terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [solution](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/screen.htm) by issuing

```
screen -d -m <command ...>
```

Then I get a new error saying

```
Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen': Permission denied
```

I then search and found a workaround [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1195962/cannot-make-directory-var-run-screen-permission-denied)

Now I can execute screen -d -m  successfully.

Thank you all.

Answer (score -4):

Alternatively, You can start the session within "hohup" and send to background

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you mean `nohup` instead of `hohup`?  Please [edit] your answer to fix.

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `to maximise your chance` of getting your answer **[accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** and **[upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)**, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.